# What's the best way to melt a list into a vector?

Tags: r

I'd like to melt this:

```
test = list( one = "joe" , two = c( "john" , "jane" ) )
```

Into a character vector:

```
c( "joe" , "john" , "jane" )
```

I tried melt() in the reshape package, but that results in a data.frame where strings are treated as factors, so I'd have to do something like:

```
as.character( melt( test )$value )
```

Is there a shorter/faster way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
unlist(test)
```

(my answer needs to be more than 30 characters!)

Comment: That is as concise as it gets!  Thanks...I figured there was something really basic I was missing!

Comment: If you're dealing with a named list like in the example, you can speed up the unlisting by specifying `unlist(test, use.names = FALSE)` (provided you don't need the names in the resulting vector). For large lists, this can make a noticeable performance difference