# apply rbind for all column of a data frame in r

Tags: r, rbind, rscript

I have a data frame like this :

```
a <- 1:5
b <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
c <- c(15,49,41,29,7)

df1 <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I want to make a single column by doing r bind.
Currently I am doing like this :

```
x <- as.data.frame(df1$a)
y <- as.data.frame(df1$b)
z <- as.data.frame(df1$c)

colnames(x)[1] <- "x"
colnames(y)[1] <- "x"
colnames(z)[1] <- "x"

e <- rbind(x,y,z)
```

But problem is if number of column is huge like 50-60 it is very difficult to do the same.
Need help...

Comment: probably you should explain why you want to do such a thing. if your different columns are not of the same class (as in your example) it is quite "dangerous" to fuse them

Comment: @Cath please let me know if class is same what to do.

Comment: if all the column are of the same type, you can just unlist your data.frame (`unlist(df1)`) to get a vector containing all values. I don't think you need a 1-column data.frame but we're missing a bit of context here

Comment: @Sotos why did you delete your answer? it was working properly..

Comment: you can have a look [at this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7196491/4137985) as a data.frame is a list and at [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34368598/4137985)

Comment: I undeleted my answer but you should really be careful with such operations as they can cause problems down the road

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unlist` to coerce it to a vector, i.e. `unlist(df1)` but you have to make sure that you don't have any factor columns and also keep in mind that by doing that you are coercing your numeric columns to characters.

For your example above, this will not work as `df1$b` is a factor. You will have to convert it to character first.

Comment: actually `b` is a factor

Comment: @Cath indeed. Converting as.character